# My jQuery .click function only works on the last div generated by a php function

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working on a portfolio for someone who isn't very technically proficient at the moment. He is going to need to regularly add new content to his portfolio, which means that either he is going to need to learn how to hard code new buttons, text, and pictures into his website, or I'm going to need to regularly do this for him.

My current design for the website includes a php script that automatically populates a navigation bar based on the contents of a directory. My goal is that when a user clicks on one of the navigation buttons, it will trigger an ajax event that calls a php script to load all of the images from that particular event into my main content div. Here is the script for the nav bar:

```
<div id="eventsbar">
<div id="eventslistleft">
<?php
$eventlist = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir('events'));
foreach($eventlist as $i => $event){
if($i == 0 || $i % 2 == 0){
echo '<div class="eventbutton" id='.$event.'><img src="/events/'.$event.'/0.jpg"></div>';
}
}
?>
</div>
<div id="infobutton">
</div>
<div id="eventslistright">
<?php
$eventlist = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir('events'));
foreach($eventlist as $i => $event){
if($i != 0 && $i % 2 != 0){
echo '<div class="eventbutton" id='.$event.'><img src="/events/'.$event.'/0.jpg"></div>';
}
}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

The rendered HTML:

```html
<div id="eventsbar">
<div id="eventslistleft">
<div class="eventbutton" id="fifth"><img src="/events/fifth/0.jpg"></div>
<div class="eventbutton" id="fourth"><img src="/events/fourth/0.jpg"></div>
<div class="eventbutton" id="third"><img src="/events/third/0.jpg"></div></div>
<div id="infobutton"></div>
<div id="eventslistright">
<div class="eventbutton" id="first"><img src="/events/first/0.jpg"></div>
<div class="eventbutton" id="second"><img src="/events/second/0.jpg"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the script to call the image load function:

```
<script>
$(".eventbutton").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
    currentevent = this.id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "scripts/load.php",
        data: "cevt="+currentevent,
        success: function(msg){
                    $('#Content').html(msg);
                }
    });
});
</script>
```

For whatever reason, though, the click event only triggers when I click on the last navigation button. I suspect that the click event is not triggering at all because I do not see the alert that says "clicked"  when I click any navigation buttons except for the one which is rendered last. Does anyone have experience with a similar issue? Any suggestions for what I can do to correct this problem?

Comment: Without the corresponding HTML, who knows?

Comment: Do you have some errors in browser console when clicking on other nav buttons?

Comment: try $(document).on("click",".eventbutton", function(){

Comment: @ceejayoz It's very important to mention, that we want to see rendered HTML, not a lot of strange bad-formatted PHP code...

Comment: maybe you and your friend should look at content managment systems, as that's basically what you need, something like Wordpress!

Comment: Added the corresponding php code. No errors in my console when clicking on the other buttons.

Comment: @DanTruitt can you provide rendered HTML (which you can see in browser and with which jQuery works) instead of your PHP code?

Comment: Maybe one or more of your `$event` variables are unsuitable to be used as an ID? You could at least wrap the id in speachmarks: `<div class="eventbutton" id="'.$event.'">`

Comment: Wrapping the id in speechmarks didn't fix the problem.

Comment: FYI your rendered output wont be `fifth,fourth,third,first,second` but `first,third,fifth,second,fourth`

Comment: may be try adding event in the div in php itself like onclick='functionName('.$event.')'

Comment: @DanTruitt Joao Paulo mentioned problem 30 minutes ago: there should be `$(document).ready`. Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvevzcr0/1/).

Comment: @Regent with direct html it will work even out side of $(document).ready

Comment: @Moob I don't have any of the actual images that need to go on the website yet, so I'm using filler directories titled "first" "second" "third" etc. The glob function gets the array in alphabetical order and oddly enough my output is fifth, fourth, third, first, second.

Comment: @suchit no, it will not: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvevzcr0/2/). There only way it will work without `$(document).ready` - if script is in the end of `<body>`.

Comment: @Regent copy his posted html and script and run it.it will work.don't even use body.

Comment: @Regent my script is at the end of <body> so it should work. Adding $(document).ready did not help.

Comment: @DanTruitt if it is at the of `<body>`, then yes, it will not help. But code works in fiddle, doesn't it? So there is no problem with `.click()`...

Comment: @Regent the code works in fiddle because the fiddle is using the rendered code. For whatever reason my code doesn't reliably work when I use the php, and I don't really have an option there.

Comment: @DanTruitt ok, I re-read question. Does `$(document).on("click", ".eventbutton", function() {` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvevzcr0/3/)) fix your problem?

Comment: @Regent No, it doesn't fix my problem. The function still only triggers when I click on the last div to be created (in this case, id="third").

Comment: @DanTruitt do you use jQuery 1.7+?

Comment: I'm using jquery 2.1.1

Comment: @DanTruitt then I have no ideas at all, even bad ideas... But if you will solve problem (and it will not obvious error), please write to me to let me know it in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($i != 0 && $i % 2 != 0){
   echo '<div class="eventbutton" id='.$event.'><img src="/events/'.$event.'/0.jpg"></div>';
}
```

Because all the the buttons are dynamically added to the form so the event should be attached to the parent.

```
$("#eventslistright .eventbutton").on( "click", function() {});
```

or

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".eventbutton" ,function(){});
```

If you add `navigation button` dynamically in page you should use 
`.on()` [Read more ...](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or `.live() Until version 1.7` [Read more ...](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$("#eventsbar .eventbutton").on( "click", function() {
    alert("clicked");
    currentevent = this.id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "scripts/load.php",
        data: "cevt="+currentevent,
        success: function(msg){
                    $('#Content').html(msg);
       }
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/5rqydgqk/)

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and is removed in jQuery 1.9. Do not use it at all. You can use `$(document).on("click", ".eventbutton", function() {`

Comment: It should be, for example, `$(document).on`, but definitely not `$( ".eventbutton" ).on`. Right now the whole idea of using event delegation doesn't work.

Comment: No luck with this solution.

Comment: @Dan Truitt see demo in my answer. It working correctly.

Comment: @Hamix you're using the rendered HTML. I've never had any difficulties getting the click function of java to work with hard html in any of the various slightly different implementations that exist. Neither your solution, nor any of the other solutions that have been offered here, have proven successful.

Answer (score -1):

If your code loads elements dynamically then method .click wouldn't work because it is declared for elements already existing during js loading. To add some click event action for js loaded elements you must use .on with parameter 'click'. Example above:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("html").on('click','.eventbutton', function(){
    var currentevent = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(currentevent);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "scripts/load.php?cevt=" + currentevent,
        success: function(msg){
            $('#Content').html(msg);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work in my particular case.

Comment: I made some change in my code, but I'm not sure what problem you have with this. Content is not loading or nothing happen when you click on the button?

Comment: Nothing is happening when I click the button.

Comment: ok, so copy now code I wrote up there but comment this ajax request and tell me if anything happen when you click on the button?

Comment: @Joint you should provide at least a little explanation what and why you have actually done, not "try and use it".